# PowerBuilder and Visual Studio files in same StarTeam project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, powerbuilder, starteam

We have a system that is largely written in PowerBuilder 11.5 and we are using a single StarTeam project to hold the source code.

Now we are wanting to add some related websites developed in ASP.NET with Visual Studio 2010 to source control as well. We would like them to be able to share the same set of Change Requests as the PowerBuilder code. Since in StarTeam Change Requests sets are tied to a StarTeam project this means we will have to put the web sites into the same StarTeam project as the PowerBuilder files.

Are there any pitfalls related to putting projects from different development environments into the same StarTeam project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we do with Merant and Subversion is create a folder within the project for the Pb code.  So the code from a variety of places is in the same project, but there is a subfolder within the project for the different sources.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm leaning towards -- creating a sub-folder for the .NET projects.

Answer (score 0):

CRs are not limited to a single project.  You can create CRs and share them wherever you want on the same server instance, even between projects.  You'd need to be careful to not branch the shared version so any CR property changes are visible to both sides.  This isn't automatic, but possible at least.

Having the two projects share a single view is probably easier, especially if a single change needs to edit files in both products.